# Azure Cosmos DB Python SDK : How to read change feed?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

This question may be trivial but I cannot figure out how to read change feed using PyDocument DB and the documentation isn't very helpful.

Until now, I've been using native Cosmos DB connector and there I could just set these parameters inside of the config :

```
"ReadChangeFeed" :
"ChangeFeedQueryName" :
"ChangeFeedStartFromTheBeginning" :
"ChangeFeedUseNextToken" : 
"RollingChangeFeed" :
```

But the very same options won't work with the Python SDK so I cannot do something like this.

```
query = client.QueryDocuments(collLink, querystr, options= { 'enableCrossPartitionQuery': True, "ReadChangeFeed" :True})

# Push into list `elements`
elements = list(query)
```

I have tried to find some samples but unsuccessfully.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please check our official samples here to read the Change Feed, you can use the `QueryItemsChangeFeed` method: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-python/tree/master/samples/ChangeFeedManagement

Here is a snippet:

```
options = {}
options["startFromBeginning"] = True

response = client.QueryItemsChangeFeed(collection_link, options)
for doc in response:
    print(doc)
```

Where `client` is an instance of a Cosmos DB client and `collection_link` is the name based link to the Collection you want to read, for example `dbs/<your-db>/colls/<your-collection>`.

`startFromBeginning` is a flag that will start to read from the beginning of the history of the collection, optionally (also included in the Github sample) is the use of `startTime`.